# Gradient descent stuck in local minima?

Tags: python, numerical-methods, gradient-descent, root-finding

I'm running gradient descent to find a root for a system of nonlinear equations and I am wondering how you might detect if the method is stuck at the local minima, because I believe with the settings I am using this might be the case? my initial values are [-2, -1], tolerance of 10^-2 and 20 iterations. One thing I had read upon was that if the residual begins to flat line or begins to decrease incredibly slowly, it could be an indicator of the method being stuck in the local minima though, I am not entirely sure. I have graphed my residual with its iteration as the values of my iterates for each iteration and I'm wondering how I might know if it's stuck at the local minima.

```
def system(x):
    F = np.zeros((2,1), dtype=np.float64)
    F[0] = x[0]*x[0] + 2*x[1]*x[1] + math.sin(2*x[0])
    F[1] = x[0]*x[0] + math.cos(x[0]+5*x[1]) - 1.2
    return F
 
def jacb(x):
    J = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=np.float64)
    J[0,0] = 2*(x[0]+math.cos(2*x[0]))
    J[0,1] = 4*x[1]
    J[1,0] = 2*x[0]-math.sin(x[0]+5*x[1])
    J[1,1] = -5*math.sin(x[0]+5*x[1])
    return J


iterates, residuals = GradientDescent('system', 'jacb', np.array([[-2],[-1]]), 1e-2, 20, 0);
```

[FullGradientDescent.py](https://pastebin.com/cmJn3WxC)
[GradientDescentWithMomentum](https://pastebin.com/6HYnfh8P)

I'm testing usually with 20 iterations but I did 200 to illustrate the slowing down of the residual
[image]

[image]

**Marat** suggested using GD with momentum.
Code changes:

```
dn = 0
gamma = 0.8
dn_prev = 0
while (norm(F,2) > tol and n <= max_iterations):
    J = eval(jac)(x,2,fnon,F,*fnonargs)
    residuals.append(norm(F,2))
    
    dn = gamma * dn_prev+2*(np.matmul(np.transpose(J), F))
    dn_prev = dn

    lamb = 0.01       
    x = x - lamb * dn
```

Residual using GD with momentum
[image]

**lastchance** suggested doing a contour plot, this seems to show the behaviour of the algorithm but it still does not converge?
[image]

Comment: Unless the function is known to be convex, GD does not guarantee conversion to global minimum. In practice we prop GD with some means of escaping shallow minima like adding momentum, for exactly this reason.

Comment: @Marat Thanks for the reply, I have updated the post to use momentum. I think the implementation is correct and it seems like the residual looks less like it's getting stuck at local minima? It still does not seem to converge however

Comment: @lastchance I updated the post to a contour plot and behaviour of GD with momentum but im not able to get it to converge

Comment: Sorry, I realised you are looking for a root, not a minimum. Your first equation can be written as sin(2x) = -(x^2+2y^2) and your second as cos(x+5y)=1.2-x^2. The first equation then means that IF there is a root then (x,y) lies within the ellipse x^2+2y^2<=1 and that x is necessarily negative. The second equation requires x^2 >= 0.2. So IF there is a root then it can only have an x value in the range [-1,-sqrt(0.2)] and y value in the range [-sqrt(1/2),+sqrt(1/2)]. Can you tighten your contour plot to that region?

Answer (score 1):

Your two equations can be written as curves y(x):

y=+-sqrt( (-sin(2x)-x^2) / 2 )

y = (arccos(1.2-x^2)-x)/5

These are the blue and red lines, respectively, on the graph below. Note that both have two branches. The points of intersection are the two roots.
[image]
The roots can be found by multi-dimensional Newton-Raphson:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sin, cos

#=======================================================================

def solver( eqns, x ):
    MAXITER = 1000
    TOL = 1.0e-10
    iter, residuals = 1, 1.0
    while iter <= MAXITER:
        print( x )
        F = Function( eqns, x )
        residuals = np.linalg.norm( F )
        if residuals <= TOL: break
        J = Jacobian( eqns, x )
        try: 
            deltax = np.linalg.solve( J, F )
        except np.LinAlgError:
            print( "Unable to solve" )
            break
        x = x - deltax
        iter += 1
    return x, residuals <= TOL

#=======================================================================

def Function( eqns, x ):
    F = np.zeros_like( x )
    for i, f in enumerate( eqns ): F[i] = f( x )
    return F

#=======================================================================

def Jacobian( eqns, x ):
    SMALL = 1.0e-6
    N = len( x )
    J = np.zeros( ( N, N ) )
    for i in range( N ):
       for j in range( N ):
           xplus  = x.copy();   xplus [j] = x[j] + 0.5 * SMALL
           xminus = x.copy();   xminus[j] = x[j] - 0.5 * SMALL
           J[i,j] = ( eqns[i]( xplus ) - eqns[i]( xminus ) ) / SMALL
    return J

#=======================================================================

eqns = [ lambda x: x[0] ** 2 + 2 * x[1] ** 2 + sin( 2 * x[0] ),
         lambda x: x[0] ** 2 + cos( x[0] + 5 * x[1] ) - 1.2   ]
x = np.array( [-0.8, 0.5 ] )
#x = np.array( [-0.8, -0.1 ] )          # alternative root
x, result = solver( eqns, x )
if result:
    print( "Root: ", x )
else:
    print( "No root found" )

#=======================================================================
```

For the first starting point you get:

```
[-0.8  0.5]
[-0.85082789  0.38764034]
[-0.8407059   0.37917738]
[-0.84056296  0.37906059]
[-0.84056293  0.37906057]
Root:  [-0.84056293  0.37906057]
```

For the second starting point you get:

```
[-0.8 -0.1]
[-1.01262867 -0.06737605]
[-0.96586428 -0.0665185 ]
[-0.96353139 -0.06643953]
[-0.96352546 -0.06643926]
[-0.96352546 -0.06643926]
Root:  [-0.96352546 -0.06643926]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed work in this post! While Newton's method might converge, I'm interested in how to get gradient descent to get to the solution and If it can't I'm trying to understand why it's not able to.

Comment: @Krellex, I don't use gradient descent very much, so it's not easy to comment. However, if you plot contour maps of your two functions F0 and F1 you will find that they cross at roughly 90 degrees near the roots. So, if you try to reduce one rapidly then the other stays nearly constant. Also, F1 changes much faster, so influences the descent direction much more. Finally, do you need lambda as small as 0.01?

Comment: I'm also unable to run the Python code that you linked to, so it's difficult to test. Can you check that you have uploaded the latest running code.

Comment: Sorry about that. What error are you getting when trying to run?

Comment: Well, first of all I need to explicitly import math. After that I get a deprecation warning (probably important here) where you set F[]: ```Conversion of an array with ndim > 0 to a scalar is deprecated, and will error in future. Ensure you extract a single element from your array before performing this operation.``` The actual fail error is ```arr, residuals = GradientDescent('system', 'jacb', np.array([[-2],[-1]]), 1e-2, 200, 0); in GradientDescent
    J = eval(jac)(x,2,fnon,F,*fnonargs)
TypeError: jacb() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have updated the code. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Krellex, you need to start from a better point (see my much-earlier comment). If you start from (-0.8,0.0) instead of (-2,-1) you WILL find (the lower) root with your code.

Comment: And if you start from (-0.8,0.5) you WILL find the upper root with your code. So all is good!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test it and get back to me. The initial guess is not the best, but could gradient descent with momentum reach it using a higher iteration count? I've updated the post to include my gradient descent with momentum, wondering if you would not mind investing this one as well? Would help clear a lot of confusion for me.

Comment: @Krellex, your second code works fine. It finds a root without having to move to a better starting position.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. It managed to find the root from initial guess -2,-1?

Comment: Yes, your second code managed to find it from there. The other code didn't.

Comment: Thanks for confirming and helping me out. Would you mind editing your answer post slightly so I can accept the answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255966/discussion-between-krellex-and-lastchance).

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your system as follow:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def system(x):
    return np.array([
        x[0]*x[0] + 2*x[1]*x[1] + np.sin(2*x[0]),
        x[0]*x[0] + np.cos(x[0] + 5*x[1]) - 1.2
    ])
```

Create some room to plot contour around minima:

```
xlin = np.linspace(-2, 2, 200)
ylin = np.linspace(-2, 2, 200)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlin, ylin)
Z = system([X, Y])
```

Solve the system around potential solution you have identified:

```
solutions = np.array([
    optimize.fsolve(system, x0=[0, 0]),
    optimize.fsolve(system, x0=[-1, 0]),
    optimize.fsolve(system, x0=[-1, 0.5])
])

# array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ],
#       [-0.96352546, -0.06643926],
#       [-0.84056293,  0.37906057]])
```

Confirm returned points actually are solutions:

```
system(solutions.T).T

# array([[ 0.00000000e+00, -2.00000000e-01],   # Not converged
#       [ 8.88178420e-16,  6.66133815e-16],
#       [-2.22044605e-15, -4.88498131e-15]])
```

Plot the whole thing to confirm solutions:

```
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.contour(X, Y, np.log10(np.sqrt(Z[0]**2 + Z[1]**2)), 30, cmap="jet")
axe.plot(*solutions.T, linestyle="none", marker="o")
axe.grid()
```

[image]

The first point `(0,0)` is not a solution, solver fails:

```
optimize.fsolve(system, x0=[0, 0], full_output=True)
# (array([0., 0.]),
# {'nfev': 15,
#  'fjac': array([[-1.00000000e+00, -2.54340978e-08],
#         [ 2.54340978e-08, -1.00000000e+00]]),
#  'r': array([-3.12495738e+12,  2.10079410e+06, -5.44853621e-02]),
#  'qtf': array([5.08681955e-09, 2.00000000e-01]),
#  'fvec': array([ 0. , -0.2])},
# 5,
# 'The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the improvement from the last ten iterations.')
```

Based on [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html):

> The solution (or the result of the last iteration for an unsuccessful
> call).

Based on those information, you can confirm your code did find one of the two roots of your system over the domains, the additional critical point at `(0,0)` is not solution.